# How can I make the AVFrame rotate 90 degrees? Try to use the FFmpeg API instead of using a for loop

Tags: ffmpeg

Because AVFrame is yuv data, I want him to rotate a certain angle, and I don't want to use a for loop, because it is too time consuming, so what API can ffmpeg do this?

Comment: Can't you just use the `transpose` filter?

Comment: Yes, build a filter graph.

Comment: @slhck  Thank you very much, but can you suggest how to use the ffmpeg API to do this?

Comment: @szatmary  Thank you very much, but can you suggest how to use the ffmpeg API to do this?

Comment: You don’t just “use the api” you must construct a filter graph with a buffer/buffersink and connect the pads. Then use the send/receive methods. There is an example in the ffmpeg source examples folder.

Comment: @szatmary  Do you mean to initialize a "transpose" filter, and then use this filter for a certain avFrame. After the filter is applied, is the avFrame rotated by a certain angle?

Comment: Not a filter, a filter graph, where one node is the transpose filter, but you also need a buffer/buffersink. Please look at the example code.

Comment: @szatmary
 I saw the example you said, but when I changed the output format from AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8 to AV_PIX_FMT_NV21, the saved avframe has a green border to the right; and according to my observation, the avframe's linesize[0] and linesize[1] are both 1088. Why is this? The width and height of the original video is 1920x1080.

Comment: thats a new question. new questions should get a new posting.

Comment: @szatmary   i solve this question  very thank you！